# Add option for custom font size in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am developing an app in this app there are many text files.
User clicks on a button and a files is loaded on new screen.

This file contains only text but few lines with font size 15 and other lines with font size 10. User can change font size from settings for that file.

What is right way to load the file so user increase or decrease font size?

I think attributed text is not right choice for this.

Comment: _"I think attributed text is not right choice for this."_ Why not?

Comment: Because there are many files and all have large text and I will have to keep text in code instead of files. I want function as it’s implemented in an app of Gutka Sahib. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sundar-gutka/id431446112

Answer (score 1):

In this use-case `NSAttributedString` is my best friend, and I would go with him.

Having said that, you do not have to keep large text in code files, keep the files

1. In app bundle, you can load file from App Bundle using

   ```
   if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file1", ofType: "txt"), let text = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. In a remote location, you can load String from remote URL using

   ```
   if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.org"), let text = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
       ...
   }
   ```

> Add option for custom font size

You can add HTML tags in your text and use CSS styles, here is an example

```
let headerFont = UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 30)!
let headerStyle = ".heading{font-family:\(headerFont.fontName);font-size:\(Int(headerFont.pointSize));color:#000}"

let commonFont = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 22)!
let commonStyle = "*{font-family:\(commonFont.fontName);font-size:\(Int(commonFont.pointSize));color:#666}"

let htmlData = Data("<style>\(commonStyle)\(headerStyle)</style>\(text)".utf8)
let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: How to set two fonts like one for headings and other for description?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can also paste this gist in playground https://gist.github.com/r-aamir/0f92e2bae59ab07ad3422a3a4f8d8d19